# AndroidStudio - change default src folder name

Tags: java, android, gradle

In AndroidStudio, which I recently started using, the primary folder for source code displayed in the Project view is called `java`, and the files are stored in `app/src/main/java/com/...`

I would like the folder to be called `src` instead of `java` (for the purpose of interfacing with a separate tool). Is there any way I can do this and still have the project compile normally in Android Studio? I tried renaming the folder from `java` to `src`, and it disappears from the project view - I'm assuming I need to tell Gradle where to find the source files, but I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Leave the default maven/gradle structure alone. It is highly optimal for development as well as testing. It is easy to use and easy to work with. What other tool are you trying to use?

Comment: See [45.7. Working with source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: @JaredBurrows The tool I'm using is SPARTA, an analysis tool for Android apps. I believe it typically uses Eclipse, which is why it automatically looks for a "src" directory. My app is already developed and tested, and I only need AndroidStudio to make sure it continues to compile from this point forward, so I decided that it's worlds easier to change one directory name than to attempt to modify the SPARTA toolset, which is largely undocumented and difficult to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way I can do this and still have the project compile normally in Android Studio?

Add a `sourceSets` closure to `app/build.gradle` file, telling Gradle the new location of your Java code. Rename your directory to match, and then sync the project files with Gradle.

For example, here is an `app/build.gradle` file from a newly-created Android Studio project, where I added the `sourceSets` closure:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/src']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Here, I am saying that the `main` sourceset's Java code resides at `src/main/src` relative to the module root.

After adding that, I renamed `java/` to `src/` as you described, then used the yellow banner in the `build.gradle` editor to sync the files. Android Studio seems happy, and the project compiles normally.

Comment: This also works if you want to replace ```src``` folders for whatever reason and Android Studio does not show the new ```src``` folder on the Android view. Just complete the replacement process, and add the ```sourceSet``` closure with ```java.srcDirs``` field set to ```['src/']``` in your ```build.gradle``` and finally click Sync Project with Gradle Files.